# Is it possible to import a color palette and have stroke, fill, and gradient color stop colors refer to the palette?

Tags: svg, import, color-palette

I am experimenting with the idea of creating an SVG icon set. What I would like to do is define a color palette and have stroke, fill, and gradient color stop colors refer to colors in the palette, which would be imported somehow by each of the SVG files. This way, if I wanted to create a grayscale version of the icon set, or adapt the colors for a particular kind of colorblindness, then I could just change the palette.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any XML file, SVG supports CSS.

**mystyle.css**

```
rect {
  fill: red;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 3
}
```

**SVG file referencing mystyle.css**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="mystyle.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     width="10cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
  <rect x="200" y="100" width="600" height="300"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please help with this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319537/html-5-inline-svg-and-namespace-awareness-for-svg-dom

Comment: +1 This is a good solution, and it works well in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. However, Mac's file preview, GIMP, and Inkscape don't understand the stylesheet, so everything appears black.

Comment: You could also try using an @import in a `<style>` element, but I suspect it won't be any more successful then the above.

Comment: @BigBadaboom: Yes, you are right. `@import` in a `<style>` element does not work, and presumably any other import mechanism for external resources would not work. I also tried copying the applicable styles from the stylesheet. Mac OS 10.9.2 file preview supports that. GIMP 2.8.10 appears not to have any support for `<style>`. Inkscape 0.48.4 r supports `<style>` somewhat, but not, for example, the `stop-color` attribute: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/CSS_Support